# I need to unistall expose.sh on Linux

Tags: webhooks, laravel-7, linux-mint

I installed the expose.sh webhook service by mistake. Now I need to uninstall it, as it doesn't work for laravel projects I have a Linux Mint operating system. I've tried

```
sudo apt remove expose.sh
```

and

```
composer remove expose.sh
```

but neither works.

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: I used this command  ( curl -s expose.sh/sh/install-linux.sh | sudo bash )    from their website https://expose.sh/install/